# JointController SetAngularVelocityTarget?

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello it's me again,

I am using a JointController to move my robots, however I need to set an angularVelocity and I couldn't find this function in the documentation.

Does this exist ? If no, what other way to do do I have ? thank you in advance !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15956/jointcontroller-setangularvelocitytarget-?/) by [shenki](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3179/shenki/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 39 on 2017-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `JointController` class uses the [SetVelocityTarget](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/5.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1JointController.html#aa955b4b4ce49e67a8154d7d174ef8619) function to set a target velocity for a joint's axis. If that joint is rotational, that will be an angular velocity given in rad/s. If it's a prismatic joint, that will be a linear velocity given in m/s.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shenki](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3179/shenki/) on 2017-04-24**:
My 4 joints are now of type revolute2 ( since I want 2 axis ), when I set a velocity it only roll on one axis, how do I do to make it rotate now (set velocity on another axis)? thank you for your answer anyway

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-04-24**:
Unfortunately, the joint controller doesn't support multi-axis joints. There's an issue open about this: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2160/jointcontroller-doesnt-support-multi-axis One solution would be to use 2 revolute joints with a dummy link in between